# Script not found when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

I am trying to convert a python script to an exe file. I have added the python script to a folder together with pyinstaller, and I use the right PATH in CMD:

```
C:\Users\ola nordmann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller>pyinstaller --onefile CreatWordDoc.py
126 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
126 INFO: Python: 3.7.5
126 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
127 INFO: wrote C:\Users\ola nordmann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller\CreatWordDoc.spec
132 INFO: UPX is not available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ola nordmann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ola nordmann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\ola nordmann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ola nordmann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\ola nordmann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\ola nordmann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller\CreatWordDoc.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "C:\Users\ola nordmann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 190, in __init__
    raise ValueError("script '%s' not found" % script)
ValueError: script 'C:\Users\ola nordmann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller\CreatWordDoc.py' not found
```

This is what it shows.

I know there are some similar questions here, but I have not found a solution yet.

Comment: Is your script `CreatWordDoc.py` in the folder: `C:\Users\ola nordmann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller` ? It might by better the run pyInstaller in the `CreatWordDoc.py` directory

Comment: What do you mean by `I have added the python script to a folder together with pyinstaller`??? Can you show us the output of the `tree` command where your script exists?

Comment: Meurice Meyer: The CreatWordDoc.py is located in

C:\Users\ola nordmann\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller

Comment: M. R.: I mean that I have added the script in a folder together with pyinstall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to first install Python from their own website instead of the Windows store. Then I had to add it to a PATH. After this it still did not work because I used Python 3.8.0, so I had to install pyinstaller development version.