# PyInstaller : script not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I want to create a simple .exe file of a simple python script with pyinstaller. I follow the guide (https://www.pyinstaller.org/) :

1. pip install pyinstaller
2. pyinstaller yourprogram.py

But I do not obtain my .exe file in the DIST folder as explained in https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html :

> In the dist folder you find the bundled app you distribute to your
> users.

I use Python 3.7.6 with anaconda. I download first the PyInstaller from [www.pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/](http://www.pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/), it is the version 4.2 but it gives me the same following error, so I tried with the latest version 5.0 which is in developpement.

In my case, I executed in the Anaconda Prompt :

```
C:\Users\David Gomez\Desktop\test>pyinstaller simple.py
```

I obtain :

```
1418 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.0.dev0
1418 INFO: Python: 3.7.6 (conda)
1418 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
1432 INFO: wrote C:\Users\David Gomez\Desktop\test\simple.spec
1434 INFO: UPX is not available.
script 'C:\Users\David Gomez\Desktop\test\simple.py' not found
```

The script is then not found. After some research, I thought the probleme was the space in my path between my name "David Gomez", so I wrote the path with quotes:

```
C:\Users\David Gomez\Desktop\test>pyinstaller "C:\Users\David Gomez\Desktop\test\simple.py"
```

But the same error remains.

Then I found another personne having the same problem ([Script not found when using pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58842773/script-not-found-when-using-pyinstaller)), but the answer is not convincing and I clearly do not want to install another python. I create a new topic because that one is not updated anymore, the proposed solution :

> I found the solution. I had to first install Python from their own website instead of the Windows store. Then I had to add it to a PATH. After this it still did not work because I used Python 3.8.0, so I had to install pyinstaller development version.

Any ideas what the problem could be? Any help or guesses are appreciated. If there is a need for further clarification, let me know.

**Edited part**

When I check my folder with the command `dir`, I obtain :

```
 C:\Users\David Gomez\Desktop\test>dir
 Le volume dans le lecteur C s’appelle Windows
 Le numéro de série du volume est 3AFA-C44C

 Répertoire de C:\Users\David Gomez\Desktop\test

15.03.2021  11:20    <DIR>          .
15.03.2021  11:20    <DIR>          ..
11.03.2021  15:52               160 simple.py.py
               1 fichier(s)              160 octets
               2 Rép(s)  166,905,487,360 octets libres
```

Then, I do the command `C:\Users\David Gomez\Desktop\test>pyinstaller "C:\Users\David Gomez\Desktop\test\simple.py"` and two new empty folders are created (build, dist) and a file *simple.spec*. Normally, if everything works corectly the folders are not empty. Now if I check again my folder with `dir` command :

```
C:\Users\David Gomez\Desktop\test>dir
 Le volume dans le lecteur C s’appelle Windows
 Le numéro de série du volume est 3AFA-C44C

 Répertoire de C:\Users\David Gomez\Desktop\test

11.03.2021  16:57    <DIR>          .
11.03.2021  16:57    <DIR>          ..
11.03.2021  16:57    <DIR>          build
11.03.2021  16:57    <DIR>          dist
11.03.2021  15:52               160 simple.py.py
11.03.2021  17:41             1,059 simple.spec
               2 fichier(s)            1,219 octets
               4 Rép(s)  166,908,215,296 octets libres
```

Simply.py is in the folder but not found by pyinstaller, I still have no idea what to do.

I do not know if it is usefull but here you have the content of the simple.spec :

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['simple.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\David Gomez\\Desktop\\test'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False) pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher) exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='simple',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True ) coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='simple')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue doesnt have to do with your pyinstaller install location, but rather the `simple.py` file doesnt exist in that directory. (At least thats what it seems like to me)

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my post. I made some errors when I copied the path. Now you can see clearly that the file exists in my folder:
C:\Users\David Gomez\Desktop\test>pyinstaller "C:\Users\David Gomez\Desktop\test\simple.py"
I am in the test folder and execute pyinstaller with the file simple.py, which is in the folder. Others ideas?

Comment: Could you run the `ls` command to see the contents of that directory? @DavidAndréGomezRomero

Comment: I am working on windows so when I do the `dir` command, I obtain :

_C:\Users\David Gomez\Desktop\test>dir
 Le volume dans le lecteur C s’appelle Windows
 Le numéro de série du volume est 3AFA-C44C

 Répertoire de C:\Users\David Gomez\Desktop\test

15.03.2021  11:20    <DIR>          .
15.03.2021  11:20    <DIR>          ..
11.03.2021  15:52               160 simple.py.py
               1 fichier(s)              160 octets
               2 Rép(s)  166,905,487,360 octets libres_ 

@101donutman

Comment: I have updated my post from the part: "Edited part". I hope this information is helpful and let me know if you have any other ideas. Thanks

Comment: Your problem is that your file is named `simple.py.py` instead of `simple.py`. Thus the file `simple.py` does not exist within that directory. @DavidAndréGomezRomero

Comment: So obvious... Sorry, I was strugle so much that I did not even see that. Your answer is perfect. Thank you a lot ! @101donutman

Answer (score 0):

it may sound weird but try typing

```
pyinstaller your_script.py.py
```

when you try creating a file with `.py` in an editor and you do not have the name to affect the file in windows (or any other operating system) the editor will create

> file.py.py

so be aware of that :)

Answer (score 0):

July 2023. Solution: I got the same issue about script not found.  How I was able to solve, finally...

1. deleted all old build and dist folders
2. renamed new_code.py to newcode.py (removed underscore)
3. transferred this newcode.py to the folder where PyInstaller was located
4. ran the command pyinstaller --onefile code.py from there.

It finally worked, to my relief! :)